# Start Firebase Service Manually

Tags: android, firebase, service, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am creating an app containing FireBase Messaging Service.
I added service to manifest:

```
 <service android:name="xxx.xxx.MyFirebaseInstanceIdService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

 <service android:name="xxx.xxx.MyFireBaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

and I have two class for getting a token and firebase message:

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        super.onTokenRefresh();
        String recent_token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("mypref", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        editor.putString("token", recent_token);
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

and messaging class:

```
public class MyFireBaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {


    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(final RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MyFireBaseMessagingService.this, AdvCreateActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("mode","notification");
        intent.putExtra("text",remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MyFireBaseMessagingService.this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MyFireBaseMessagingService.this);
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
        notificationBuilder.setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0,notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

when the app starts, firebase service starts automatically. if the device had no internet connection, then I can't receive a token. if I turn the data or wifi on, firebase won't send token!
**My question is:** how can I start firebase service manually after the application starts? (I don't want the firebase service starts at launching app!!!)

Comment: onTokenRefresh() will call only when the token change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please call the following method wherever you want to get your fcm id.

```
try {
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d("Firbase id login", "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: thanks, I just used it but it takes about two minutes or more to receive token! and it's not acceptable to me.  I think starting service during runtime manually grants faster response. what do you think?

Comment: Ok, onTokenRefresh save the token to shared preference use whenever you want. is that oke.?

Comment: No, if the device has no connection on the starting point, first, it doesn't give token and after that, onTokenrefresh won't call again!

Comment: When the connection gets the token will generate.